# rings of polynomials over $Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

An element of R is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $< r$ with coefficients from $Z_p$ (where $p$ is a prime). We use the notation $a(x)$ to represent elements of $R$. Define map $\phi :R \mapsto R$ as: $ \phi(a(x)) = a^p(x) $

---

In order to prove that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism I need to show two things:

- $ \phi(a(x)\cdot b(x))=\phi(a(x)) \cdot \phi(b(x)) $ (obvious)
- $\phi(a(x)+b(x))=\phi(a(x))+\phi(b(x))$

   

  can someone help me by giving a hint or approach to prove $\phi(a(x)+b(x))=\phi(a(x))+\phi(b(x))$

  I'm new to rings and your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In a ring of characteristic $p$, $(a+b)^p=a^p + b^p$.  Look at the binomial theorem to see why those cross terms are all zero.  This is what we call the Freshman Dream.

Comment: yeah.. got it! thanks man!

Comment: Now for another map defined for the same question, i've been trying to prove that the ring homomorphism exists iff $\phi(a(x))=a(x^p)$ (where p is a composite number)and i tried it in the same way of binomial expansion as in the earlier case for prime numbers but i'm not able to express the coefficients of the terms  $$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i} {a(x)}^ib(x)^{p-i}$$ as $pk$ for some $k \in I$ so that they can become zero and i could show $\phi(a(x)+b(x))=\phi(a(x))+\phi(b(x))$         Please help me out!

Comment: You should start a new question for this one.  It is policy that each question has its own page so that future users can find them.